# Force is to pressure as torque is to ...?

Tags: classical-mechanics, torque, noethers-theorem, continuum-mechanics

Using Noether's theorem to derive the conserved current for spacial translation symmetry, one gets that the time component is momentum and the spatial component is pressure (or stress). The continuity equation then gives a continuum equivalent of $F = \frac{dp}{dt}$.

Angular momentum is the time component of the conserved current that Noether's theorem gives for rotational symmetry. Is there a name for the spatial component? I guessed that it would be like pressure, but for torque instead of force, so maybe it would be torque per area. It seems like it something that would be used often, since pressure and torque both are, but I haven't managed to turn it up through googling.

Comment: Would torque per unit area make sense in the context of a disk sander?

Comment: @mmesser314 Maybe as a way of determining how much the sander twists the object it is sanding? I was thinking more of static situations, such as deciding how thick an axle needs to be to carry a particular torque.

Comment: Then you are thinking in terms of shear stress.